# how to set fetch type at runtime ? + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

how to set fetch type at run time in hibernate 3.2?

```
session.beginTransaction();  
Customer customer = session.get(getCustomerId());  
session.save(customer);  
session.commit();
```

if any possibility to change fetch type("lazy/eager") at run time. so,is there any impact when already defined a fetch mode i.e.,"select/join" in hibernate.mapping file?.If any wrong with question sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join fetch` to specify a specific collection to initialize.

e.g.

```
from Cat as cat
inner join fetch cat.mate
left join fetch cat.kittens
```

See more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Or you can use the [criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206761/lazy-left-outer-join-using-the-hibernate-criteria-api)

Comment: your example does not make an sense, unrelated to the values.  Hibernate links are not really helpful.