# JPA not showing null value row

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

In JPA criteria builder when order by child object property if object is null then it will not showing in the result. I want these rows also whose object is null.

Query generated by JPA finally :

```
select generatedAlias0 
from WorkOrderRogers as generatedAlias0 
where generatedAlias0.id>=0 
order by generatedAlias0.managerUser.firstname desc
```

Now if managerUser is null then that row will not show in the result.

Here one to many relationship between WorkOrderRogers and managerUser.

I have creating criteria query like this :

```
cq.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("managerUser").get("firstname")));
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35625998/4754790). Basically, you are creating an inner join, that's why there are missing rows. Create an outer join.

Comment: How to specify force outer join in JPA criteria builder ? Plz explain.

Comment: [Left join with Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206761/lazy-left-outer-join-using-the-hibernate-criteria-api).